# PHP Execute Shell Command And Retrieve The Output

Tags: php, ssh

I'm trying to retrieve the contents of a file on a remote server via SSH and display the results in a browser.  The remote server's name and address is configured on my local server with the name "router", such that from the command line I can execute the following to successfully retrieve the results:

```
ssh router "cat /var/log/messages"
```

I'm having trouble getting this to execute in PHP - I can't get the quotes escaped properly.  Here's my PHP script

```
<pre>
$command = 'ssh router \"cat /var/log/messages\"';
<?php system($command); ?>
</pre>
```

But this outputs the command string to the webpage instead of executing the command and returning the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `escapeshellarg()` to escape command argument. Please try like this

```
$host       =  escapeshellarg("user@router");
$commandArg =  escapeshellarg("/var/log/messages");
$result     = shell_exec('ssh ' . $host . ' cat ' . $commandArg);
echo $result, PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: It's important to be **extremely careful** when executing arbitrary shell commands. It's great that you're using [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php), as this is really not optional.